# How to prevent usage of loop using `replicate`

Tags: r, loops, reduce, replicate

I'm trying to simplify code looking like this

```
someFunc <- function(x) {
   return(x + 3L)
}

x <- 1L
for (i in 1:10) {
   x <- c(x, someFunc(x[length(x)]))
}
```

I was thinking about reduce like this

```
replicate(10, x <- c(x, someFunc(x[length(x)]))
```

but this does not work, since it uses a copy of `x`. How can I get the logic to work without using a loop. I think there has to be a way in R (`someFunc` should be arbitrary - I just posted it as an example).

Comment: `x <- seq(from=1L, by=3, length.out = 11)`

Comment: `replicate(10, x <<- c(x, someFunc(x[length(x)])))[[10]]`

Answer (score 0):

If your output for x is

```
> x
[1]  1  4  7 10 13 16 19 22 25 28 31
```

you could just use:

```
x <- seq(0,10) * 3 + 1
```